# How to select a column containing a specific value

Tags: r, zoo

The following data frame is converted to zoo object

```
Lines <- "Ctry  year   Carx   Brx
 A    2000    23     12
 A    2001    18     16
 A    2002    20     20
 A    2003    NA     18
 A    2004    24     NA
 A    2005    18     12
 B    2000    NA     22
 B    2001    NA     20
 B    2002    NA     14
 B    2003    NA     NA
 B    2004    18     NA
 B    2005    16     14   
 C    2000    NA     NA
 C    2001    NA     25
 C    2002    24     32
 C    2003    21     NA
 C    2004    NA     15
 C    2005    24     20
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)


    Carx.z <- read.zoo(DF[, -4], split = "Ctry", index = "year", FUN = identity)
```

Here is the result of the series Carx in zoo object

> Carx.z

```
       A  B  C
  2000 23 NA NA
  2001 18 NA NA
  2002 20 NA 24
  2003 NA NA 21
  2004 24 18 NA
  2005 18 16 24
```

How can I select the "Ctry" (That is A, B, or C) if its value for 2005 is less than or equal to 20? I mean, if the value for the year 2005 <= 20 select the related column

Comment: That's not the output I get for `Carx.z` when I run your code, but anyway: `Carx.z[, Carx.z['2005'] <= 15]`. This is basic subsetting by a logical vector.

Comment: Ok, well my comment above still applies.. just change 15 to 20. Does that not do what you need?

Comment: That is what I want,Thank you jbaums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual subsetting rules apply here. We want to return the columns for which `Carx.z['2005', ] <= 20` is `TRUE`, so the following nested subset does what you want:

```
Carx.z[, Carx.z['2005', ] <= 20]

#       A  B
# 2000 23 NA
# 2001 18 NA
# 2002 20 NA
# 2003 NA NA
# 2004 24 18
# 2005 18 16
```